# Xcode: Sent Events Disappear upon changing UIButton class to custom class

Tags: ios, xcode, class, swift, uibutton

I have created a custom UIButton class:

```
class MyButton: UIButton {
}
```

Then I added a UIButton to my storyboard and changed its class to MyButton.

Now when I right-click-drag the button to code, I am able to add Outlet but not Action. "Sent Events" section also disappears in property inspector. What could I be missing?

Comment: Xcode certainly sucks mate, I have lose so precious time with the same annoying bug yet on 8.1, it's incredible how Apple is failing on such a basic feature on a mature product, it's a shame. Restarting does not work for me though :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by saving and restarting Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

The only trick I've discovered until now is to change the button class back to UIButton, add the requested actions and then change back the class to MyButton :/
The bug is still there.

Answer (score 1):

I know this problem is almost two years old, but I ran into it today.  Restarting Xcode did not help.  I noticed in some older .xib's, that there were some linked Sent Events, but all the rest of the `touchDown` etc. options were missing.  However, after I hovered over the source on one of the remaining Sent Events, Xcode popped up a `'UIButton' is no longer a valid event source` message.  [In this link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25180), someone discovered that that problem is linked to an extension of UIButton. Sure enough, I refactored the UIButton extension we had to UIControl and all the Sent Event options returned.

Based on the OP's issue and what I read today, Apple is trying to tell us to leave their buttons alone.  :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code easy as pie

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
    self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonUnClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonUnClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpOutside)

}
func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton){
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
func buttonUnClicked(sender: UIButton){
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
```